# How to print graphics on a new line in floatrow/subfloatrow

Tags: floats, floatrow

How can I skip to a newline in a `subfloatrow` environment (`floatrow` package) after two graphics. I want to typeset two graphics `A.pdf` and `B.pdf` on the same line, `C.pdf` and `D.pdf` should be on a new line. All graphics should be part of the same `subfloatrow`, considering the labels and captions.
I'm missing part of the floatrow concept so I tried silly things like introducing newlines (`\\` and `\newline`) which of course won't work.

This is the code I used:

preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}  
    \clearpage
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\begin{subfloatrow}
        \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{A.pdf}}%
        \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{B.pdf}}%
        \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{C.pdf}}%
        \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{D.pdf}}%
        \end{subfloatrow}}
    {\caption{this is a caption}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a complete, minimal and compilable version of your document.

Comment: this should work

Comment: I edited your code because you wrote `\start{document}`. I assume you thought of writing `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I added the `subfig` package to your code to make it (except for the actual figures) compilable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each row you need to use the `subfloatrow` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}  

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
    {\begin{subfloatrow}
        \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{A.pdf}}%
        \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{B.pdf}}%
      \end{subfloatrow}
      \begin{subfloatrow}
        \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{C.pdf}}%
        \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.4\textwidth]{D.pdf}}%
      \end{subfloatrow}}
    {\caption{this is a caption}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I used the `demo` option for `graphicx` to make my example code compilable for everyone; do not use that option in your actual code.

Comment: that was what I tried first, and for some reason it didnt work, but It seems I did something wrong then! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As this caused me quite an headache: If there is only one `subfloat` in a `subfloatrow` things might break (this happens in very odd ways).
The trick is to add an empty `subfloat`. e.g. `\sidesubfloat[]{}{}`. I don't know whether this breaks other things, but it did the job for me.